# how to install sql developer (.rpm file) on lubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, oracle, sql, sqldeveloper

How to install sql developer on lubuntu 18.04

I tried the below link from Oracle (served as installation notes when you download sql developer) but that dint work.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-linux-1969676.html

Error:

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMBTr.png)

Oracle now provides .rpm files instead of .zip and all the answers on this site help you with the .zip but not .rpm

Comment: You have to use an os supported by Oracle, perhaps I. A vm

Comment: Lubuntu is per me a lighter version of Ubuntu!. So its definitely supported. I have figured out and posted answer to my own question should anyone require they could try it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to install the Oracle SQL Developer program in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu is to install *sqldeveloper-package* from the default Ubuntu repositories. sqldeveloper-package makes it possible to build a Debian package of Oracle SQL Developer. This utility will require you to download the architecture independent archive from `https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer`, identified as "Oracle SQL Developer for other platforms", "Oracle SQL Developer for Multiple Platforms" or "Oracle SQL Developer for Linux and Unix" (depending on which version you  are building), to create the Debian package from.

To install sqldeveloper-package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install sqldeveloper-package
```

After installing, you can use it to build sqldeveloper by typing:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package /path/to/arch-ind-sqldeveloper-archive
```

This puts the build package in an autogenerated folder. Use

```
sudo make-sqldeveloper-package --install /path/to/arch-ind-sqldeveloper-archive
```

to directly install it on your system. You can get an overview of all commandline options with:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package --help
```

For running sqldeveloper you can connect to and use any JDK 1.8 (e.g. openjdk-8-jdk) or above.

Comment: This mostly worked, I had to manually install the .deb files that were generated as they had + signs in them and failed to execute using the script.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install alien openjfx
```

Then:

1. Follow the link https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
2. Click "Accept license agreement" that looks like a radio button
3. Next to "Linux RPM", click "Download"  (If there is no "Linux RPM", try the previous version)
4. Choose where you want to save the file, which will be named sqldeveloper-VERSION.noarch.rpm
5. In terminal, cd to where you saved the RPM file

   ```
   sudo alien --scripts sqldeveloper-*.noarch.rpm
   sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper*.deb
   ```

Now you can run the program. In my case it got installed to `/usr/local/bin` which is in my path.  The first time you run it, make sure you do so in the foreground (do not ampersand it) because it's going to ask you to type in the path to a good JDK (the path above bin, for example `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`).

```
$ sqldeveloper
```

Et voila!

Comment: Your solution worked for me, while the accepted answer with `sqldeveloper-package` did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to finally install SQL Developer after trying a whole bunch of things. Experts please improve this answer!

I used the Alien tool/utility/command to install SQL Developer.

the file i downloaded from oracle was

"sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-1.noarch.rpm"

i converted it .deb using Alien command

amar@amar-singh:~/Downloads$ sudo alien --scripts -d sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-1.noarch.rpm

result: sqldeveloper_18.2.0.183.1748-2_all.deb generated

do right click on the generated .deb file and select option "Software install"

this should take you to your software installer window where you can see SQL Developer being installed

once done you should now be able to run sql developer if you had previously installed JDK 8

[software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XdWf.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqhEB.png)

Comment: I can't improve this answer without making so many changes in it that it would have to be posted as a separate answer. Do you want me to post another answer even though you already solved it?

Comment: Yes please post your answer. I fixed my issue by trail and error. your answer may help someone else